# CSS Body tag not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My website was working perfectly when all of a sudden any tags without a . or # suddenly stopped working on the site I'm working on (http://cravinthe.server300.com).

I've tried putting it directly into the head without the stylesheet and that doesn't seem to work either.  This happens with body, a, and so on.  This is driving me crazy and I can't figure out what's happening.

I don't know if this will help, but here is my CSS:

```
body {margin:0 auto;width:100%;background-color:#e8f4fc;overflow-x: hidden;}
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<?php /** Home Page */ ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title>Cravin The Cookie 2013</title>

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lilita+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<?php // Loads HTML5 JavaScript file to add support for HTML5 elements in older IE versions. ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question needs to be self-contained. Questions linking to live code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. As soon as you fix your problem, this question will be rendered useless. If your question can't be asked except by linking people to your live website, you can't ask your question here.

Comment: In addition to meagar's suggestion, you haven't really outlined what the problem actually *is*. Saying tags "stopped working" isn't an adequate description of an issue. You're also exceptionally vague in your second paragraph, saying you put "it" into the head, without defining what "it" actually even is!

Comment: I don't know how to better word it.  The body and a tag were working fine in the CSS.  Suddenly they weren't.  I've re-entered them, tried every combination of stylings inside them, tried putting them both directly into the head, and so on and they they aren't being recognized at all.

I don't see how it will help having my code outside of the live environment, but: 
body {margin:0 auto;width:100%;background-color:#e8f4fc;overflow-x: hidden;} in the CSS and <body></body> in my HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in `style.css` -  remove "}"

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Omnes_GirlScoutsRegular';
   // ...
} // <--- remove "}"
   font-family: 'Omnes_GirlScoutsSemibold';
   // ...
}
body {margin:0 auto;width:100%;background-color:#e8f4fc;overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I new it was an issue of context!